# Dynamic ruleset name in Less

Tags: css, less

I'm trying to replace a [less](http://lesscss.org) ruleset name with a predefined variable (according to [this](http://lesscss.org/features/#variables-feature-variable-interpolation) doc),  while this works fine when it's a class

```
@name: list;
.@{name}-sd{
    width: 100%; 
}
```

compiles to...

```
.list-sd{
    width: 100%;
}
```

but when using the method on rulset, it throws "Unrecognised input" error

```
@name: list;
@@{name}-sd:{
    width: 100%; 
};
```

any way to get the ruleset compiled correctly?
so that it'd output

```
@list-sd:{
    width: 100%; 
};
```

Comment: Why the double `@` and what output are you expecting for the second snippet? (*Edit* Ok, I get what you're trying to do and I don't think it is possible with Less. Variable and Ruleset names cannot be dynamic.)

Comment: really appreciate when a newby in SO is capable of asking a proper question nicely formatted... very rare around here...

Comment: Thanks for you help... so I think i've to use mixin like classes as the replacement of ruleset in this case :)
& thanks @webeno :)

Comment: @Harry the thanks goes to you... you may want to add your comment as an answer...

Comment: @webeno; I am looking for an official word somewhere in the Less website or the GitHub page to point to. Without citation, it looks more like a comment than an answer :)

Comment: @Harry makes sense... I know very little of Less, so will let you do the searching :)

Comment: This is basically not different from [#2702](https://github.com/less/less.js/issues/2702) ("detached rulesets" are still plain variables so....)

Comment: So in summary of #2702, a need for this feature usually means an XY-problem. E.g. let's assume you *did* define such variable, no how are you going to use it? ;)